# What are the advantages of using Sling Pipes over other way to modifying content?

Tags: java, compare, aem, sling

I am AEM developer, and now I am researching the way of working with content.

I found some articles about Sling Pipes -https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-pipes.html. I read a lot of information about SlingPipes but I haven't understood yet what are the typical use cases of Sling Pipes or typical tasks and what are the advantages of using Sling Pipes over other way of modifying content: why I can't use, for example, Groovy Console or JSP Scriplets for this as is more regular way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have never used Sling Pipes.

Judging by the limited documentation Sling Pipes does not seem to have a lot of advantages over the other APIs. It is just another way with a supposedly better readability.

Personally, I would not advice to use Sling Pipes for the following reasons:

1. Poor documentation.
2. Probably hard to write good unit tests for those pipes.
3. Depends on Java 8 Nashorn JavaScript Engine which is deprecated in Java 11 (see [JSR 335](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335)).

I guess Sling Pipes are only a viable option for throw-away code for migrations but not for production code. But if you do write throw-away code for migration you might as well use the Groovy Console.

Nevertheless, I would be interested to hear what other peoples have to say, preferably people who already used Sling Pipes.

Comment: Lack of documentation is certainly a big factor here.